# PHP + HSQLDB for unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, hsqldb

Is there a way to run in-memory database such as hsqldb?

I need it for unit testing. In Java there's no problem with it. But, unfortunately, there is a problem with it in PHP. So, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this Perl module to access HSQLDB via PHP

https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::JDBC

Answer (score 1):

Ideally for unit testing you should be mocking your data access in order to test your components in isolation - so you would use mocks and stubs to remove the dependency on the database in your tests.

Comment: I've found that sometimes it is more productive to code functional & partially integration tests where I can check almost entire stack - POST data to MVC controller action and then verify that the data has safely reached the database. This helps also to find some issues with forgotten transaction commits and data conversion issues which would be harder to locate using DAL mocks. Currently I'm using SQLite, but it has some quirks which sometimes slow me down because I have to tweak my DB migrations code to work on SQLite.

Comment: @JustAMartin These days (some four years after this answer) I use an in-memory database for tests, which means a nice clean database every time I run the suite.